# Auto keyword deduced to a pointer or array decay?

Tags: c++, pointers, auto

I'm following the tutorial from https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-iterators/

Example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array data{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    auto begin{ &data[0] };
    // note that this points to one spot beyond the last element
    auto end{ begin + std::size(data) };

    // for-loop with pointer
    for (auto ptr{ begin }; ptr != end; ++ptr) // ++ to move to next element
    {
        std::cout << *ptr << ' '; // Indirection to get value of current element
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand this initialization `auto begin{ &data[0] };`. So a pointer wasn't explicitly defined (`auto* begin{ &data[0] };`)

Did the `auto` keyword deduced it to a pointer or was it because of array decay? If the latter is the reason, I thought array decay only happened with C-style arrays.

Thanks for the help

Comment: In that context `&` is the *pointer-to* operator. So `&data[0]` is a pointer to the first element of `data`. There's no decay since the code is explicitly using a pointer. It doesn't matter if it's for a plain old C-style array, or a `std::array`, or even a `std::vector`. On that note, array decay only happens for actual, old C-style arrays.

Comment: `std::array::operator[]` returns a reference to an element. Taking the address of that results in a pointer.

Comment: `data[0]` is of type `int` (ignoring the possibility of being a reference), taking the address of an `int` results in an int pointer `int*`, thus `auto begin{&data[0]}` deduces pointer to int.

Comment: Why would you even "decay" a std array to pointers? The whole idea of using std::array is you can get rid of pointer arithmetic (of which the use is not recommded in current C++, see [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es42-keep-use-of-pointers-simple-and-straightforward)) You have `.begin()` and `.end()` on the array itself AND if you need a pointer to the first element you can use `.data()`. Also note iterators are NOT pointers (at least not conceptually)

Comment: The whole example looks like a big abuse of C++. They really do all and everything which is bad style. OK, the text of the lesson also talks about some of the drawbacks. But hey, don't start such coding please! Stop learning C if you want to program C++.

Comment: @Klaus It IS abuse